# Installed Ubuntu along side Windows 10, only boots to Windows,boot gets error, then grub menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Upon boot I get [error: failure reading sector 0x0 from `hdo'.] and then it goes to Ubuntu's grub menu. I disabled secure boot, and have tried it with Windows’ Legacy setting both enabled and disabled.

The only odd thing I did was gave all the available disk space to Ubuntu and limited Windows to what space it already occupies. I also enabled the encryption on the Home folder.

Edit: This may be unrelated, but I'll include it. I have an 8 TB external drive that is about 75% free space, but now Windows is reading it as completely full, with a capacity of only 2.36 TB. Did I accidently repartition and/or reformat my external drive?

Edit #2: It looks like I managed to install Ubuntu on my external Hard drive. The disk allocation on Windows wasn't changed. I suppose I will just redo the install with the external hard drive disconnected this time.

Comment: Did you convert external drive from gpt to MBR. IF MBR then partitioning is a max of 2TiB. MBR tech details including 2TiB limit and GPT link
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record & 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table Post this: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb` http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/

Comment: That's probably what happened. I'll be sure to comment about it. and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" this problem and am moving on to other problems. "Solved" in this case means I've learned that what I asked in my original question was based on a misunderstanding of the problem, and was not the actual problem.

What had happened was I inadvertently re-partitioned my external hard drive and installed Ubuntu there. It would only boot to Ubuntu if/when a certain combination of hard drives and flash drives were plugged into the hub at the same time. It took a while for me to figure out this pattern of events.

Unhooking all external drives was all that was needed to install Ubuntu correctly. Now both Windows and Ubuntu (with one minor exception) work perfectly. I no longer have any boot issues with Windows.

I was able to recover full use of the external hard drive by downloading and using Mini Tool Partition Wizard.

The one minor problem I'm having with Ubuntu is a series of error messages when trying to access the Windows partition and some of the partitions on the external drive. That I will research and address in new questions.

Thanks @oldfred for pointing me in the right direction.